# How can I detect if a graph contains a cycle which has sum of weight less than a certain negative number?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

Given a complete weighted graph that contains negative weight(say its adjacency matrix), how can I detect if it contains a cycle which has sum of weight less than a certain negative number(e.g. -8)?

I have read articles about how to detect a negative cycle
(https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/detect-negative-cycle-graph-bellman-ford/)
,but I want to detect a cycle which has sum of weight less than "a certain number",
and I have no idea how I can approach this problem.

Comment: @ravenspoint, I have already edited my description.

Answer (score 1):

- Copy graph setting all edge weights to 1.
- Find all cycles in graph copy
- Sort cycles found by total edge weight in original graph
- Output cycles whose total edge weight matches reuirement.